# Use of undefined type 'NSObject'

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

That's pretty much the error I'm getting, and the project does not compile. The project was just created, so should it be some configuration from Xcode? I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 2. Shouldn't the libraries import automatically? Is it possible that they aren't?

Answer (score 1):

Swift doesn't include Foundation by default. Make sure you have an `import Foundation` statement.

Comment: Nevermind. It, well, just compiled. Go figure. Betas =)

Comment: As a note, Objective-C doesn't include Foundation by default either... it's imported in the `.pch` of Objective-C projects created in Xcode.

Comment: Are you changing anything?

Comment: @nhgrif Good point. I guess my answer does imply objective-c automatically includes foundation.

Comment: I wasn't changing anything... I actually formatted the computer, reinstalled everything, and obviously now it works. Must be another beta bug, and I have no idea what happened. But the strangest thing was probably this: I create a project, add a file to it and I get errors in that file. I delete the project, straight to trash. Then I create a new project with the same name on the same place, and I get errors from the file I added to the previous project... I had never seen anything like this. And I really can't explain it.